# Plane-Ray intersection C#

Tags: game-engine, game-physics, raytracing

I have this code for plane-ray intersection: http://pastebin.com/2VuPeZ5r
I think I compute t correctly, but I need to return null if there is no intersection.
How do I check that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "no intersection"?  Any ray will intersect a plane somewhere, except for the degenerate case where the ray is exactly perpendicular to the normal of the plane.  To detect that case, test for `Vector3.Dot(Norm, ray.Dir) == 0`.

If you want to know if the intersection is in front of or behind the ray origin, test for `t > 0`.

Comment: Generally yes.  Positive `t` values are moving in the direction of `ray.Dir`; negative `t` values are moving away from `ray.Dir`.